# use fill_between in python to shade a sub area of a density curve

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to Fill_Between a sub section of a normal distribution, say the left 5%tile.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as stats
plt.style.use('ggplot')
mean=1000
std=250
x=np.linspace(mean-3*std, mean+3*std,1000)
iq=stats.norm(mean,std)
plt.plot(x,iq.pdf(x),'b')
```

Great so far.

Then I set px to fill the area between x=0 to 500

```
px=np.arange(0,500,10)
plt_fill_between(px,iq.pdf(px),color='r')
```

The problem is that the above will only show the pdf from 0 to 500 in red.
I want to show the full pdf from 0 to 2000 where the 0 to 500 is shaded?
Any idea how to create this?

Comment: You need to use `plt.fill_between` instead of `plt_fill_between`. When doing so the output looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5jET.png) which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply.

Comment: plt_fill_between was a typo in this post. In my actual code I have plt.fill_between and the result is not like what you sent me. the graph is truncated after 500.

Comment: I provided this as answer. The graph cannot be truncated from that code.

Answer (score 6):

As commented, you need to use `plt.fill_between` instead of `plt_fill_between`. When doing so the output looks like this which seems to be exactly what you're looking for.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import stats as stats
plt.style.use('ggplot')
mean=1000
std=250
x=np.linspace(mean-3*std, mean+3*std,1000)
iq=stats.norm(mean,std)
plt.plot(x,iq.pdf(x),'b')

px=np.arange(0,500,10)
plt.fill_between(px,iq.pdf(px),color='r')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: And many thanks again. I was running the code line by line in Spyder on the IPython console which produced the truncated graph. I ran it separately as a script, including the plt.show() at the end and this produced your results. Many thanks.

Comment: @KimonG If this answer solved your problem, please [consider accepting it.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You only use the x values from 0 to 500 in your np.arange if you want to go to 2000 write:

```
px=np.arange(0,2000,10)
plt.fill_between(px,iq.pdf(px),color='r')
```

Comment: Thank you Randrian. I tried this and the result is that the whole distribution 0 to 2000 is now shaded. I wanted only the 0 to 500 shaded while displaying the full 0 to 2000 distribution.