# how to fill a sub area of a density curve with python

Tags: seaborn, density-plot

I want to shade the area under the density curve for the standard normal distribution by the following ranges:

1) mean-2std , mean-std ---> in red

2) mean +std , mean+2std ---> in red

3) mean -std , mean+st --> in blue

This is a variant on the questions "Shade (fill or color) area under density curve by quantile".

the data used to draw the denisty curve is taken from a column of a dataframe.

eg: This is only part of the data. The column has 256 values.

```
    Gap
1   -3.260010
2   -7.790009
3   -1.179993
4    2.270019
5    9.000000
6   -4.930023
7   -7.920014
```

To draw the plot I did the following code:

```
sns.kdeplot(TeslaStock18_19['Gap'], label = 'Gap Density', color = 'darkblue')
```

Considering all the data, I found out that the distribution is normal. This allows me to use the Empricial rule (68-95) to make some statitical consideraton.

What I would like to obtain is the following plot:

https://www.nku.edu/~statistics/images/Using_1.gif

N.B. I am starting to use Python, It is for a Univeristy project.

This is what I tried to do but it does not fill me completely the area

```
ptx = np.linspace(meanGap-std, meanGap+std) pty = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(ptx,meanGap,stdGap) plt.fill_between(ptx, pty, color='#0b559f', alpha='0.35')
```

Comment: Did you look at the matplotlib or seaborn homepages if they have anything to draw a filled area?

Comment: Yes I did and I did not manage to find this particular example. I found this page http://hamelg.blogspot.com/2015/11/python-for-data-analysis-part-22.html that explains something like this but I tried to do the code and it did not really work

Comment: See e.g. [use fill_between in python to shade a sub area of a density curve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51442329/use-fill-between-in-python-to-shade-a-sub-area-of-a-density-curve)

Comment: I had a look at that but it only works with random values, I need to do this by plotting the values of the dataframe

Comment: This may help https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/fill_between_demo.html

Comment: `ptx = np.linspace(meanGap-std, meanGap+std)
pty = scipy.stats.norm.pdf(ptx,meanGap,stdGap)

plt.fill_between(ptx, pty, color='#0b559f', alpha='0.35')`                                             This is what I tried to do but it does not fill me completely the area.